# Change text in another application NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, runtime

I'm a little stuck. I have successfully changed the text in normal `TextBoxes` in said application but am stuck on changing this one. Im not sure what this is called so I have called it a scroll `TextBox`, also it will only accept numbers not letters.

The code im using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
const int WM_SETTEXT = 0X000C;

public void Main(IntPtr handle, string text)
{
     SendMessage(handle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, 555);
}
```

I have also tried changing `lParam` into a `StringBuilder` which has worked in other `TextBoxes` but hasnt for this one.

This is the type of TextBox.

[image: Image1]

Using windows defender there isn't a Edit child like the usual `TextBoxes`. The only handle I have is for the whole element.

[image: Image2]

What are my choices here to be able to get that text changed?

Comment: You can use SendMessage to set the Text to the EDIT child control of a `NumericUpDown`. Get the child with [FindWindowExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexw) or [EnumChildWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows). Which one depends on how you get those window handles in the first place. The class name of the Child contains `"EDIT"`. There are just 2 children classes.

Comment: @Jimi This doesn't seem to be the normal System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown by Microsoft, but some component from a third party vendor. The normal NumericUpDown by Microsoft does not show its value as window Caption when inspected and mxadam says there are no child windows in this case.

Comment: @NineBerry  Yes, the MS `NumericUpDown` shows the numeric value as window caption. The class name looks the same, too.

Comment: Since you're trying to set some text to an EDIT control, send it text, not an `int`: `SendMessage(handle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "55");`. Use the other form of `lParam`.

Comment: @jimi No, it doesn't. Only the EDIT child control shows the value as caption, not the actual control. https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7rhJ.png

Comment: @NineBerry  Well, I was referring to the child EDIT class window caption, not the parent class. You are right, however, in that what appears to be the parent class, here, has a text and shouldn't. But I don't know the tool that is used to show those values and how it works. The OP should test this with Spy++, to compare notes. A similar control that has a text but doesn't expose its EDIT control is the `DateTimePicker` class. This class shows its text as caption. But the class name is different.

Comment: @mxadam: What is the foreign software? Do you know what Third party UI libraries it uses? What does your attempt look like to use StringBuilder?

Comment: I may give up going this route. Its trading software which im trying to set automated entries based on news as they dont have an api. Seems like its using infragistics  for the ui but im not sure if this numericupdown is using that.

Comment: There's always [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Answer (score 0):

The control is known as a [NumericUpDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/numericupdown-control-overview-windows-forms). The text is a representation of the numerical value that it holds, unlike a traditional textbox where you may parse the text to get a number. Depending on your intentions, you may need to find a way to change the underlying numerical value to effectively modify this type of control from another process.